# Ordering FeatureGroups

Tags: leaflet, layers, features, feature-layer, sorting

I'm using Leaflet right now and I have issues on ordering a list of FeatureGroups.
Each feature group is either an imageOverlay or a list of Features

I tried using bringToFront / bringToBack and it's working well with FeatureGroups containing a layer of imageOverlay but not with layers containing Features.

What am I missing ?

```
displayLayer(layer): void {
    const fg: L.FeatureGroup = L.geoJSON();

    if (layer.features !== null && layer.features.length > 0) {
      for (const sc of layer.features) {
        const feature = {};
        feature[`type`] = 'Feature';
        feature[`geometry`] = JSON.parse(sc.geometrie);

        const l: L.GeoJSON = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(feature)));
        fg.addLayer(l);
      }
    } else {
      const bounds = JSON.parse(layer.bounds)
      const c1 = L.latLng(bounds.coordinates[0][1], bounds.coordinates[0][0])
      const c2 = L.latLng(bounds.coordinates[1][1], bounds.coordinates[1][0])
      const imgCalque = L.imageOverlay(layer.url, L.latLngBounds(c1, c2));

      fg.addLayer(imgCalque);
    }

    if (fg.hasLayer) {
      this.carte.addLayer(fg);
      this.visibleLayers.set(layer.id, fg);
    }
  }

bringToFront(layer): void {
    const fg = this.visibleLayers.get(layer.id);
    if (fg !== undefined) {
      fg.bringToFront();
    }
  }

  bringToBack(layer): void {
    const fg = this.visibleLayers.get(layer.id);
    if (fg !== undefined) {
      fg.bringToBack();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing your code and some more explanation on the basis of code any solution would be just guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post.

Comment: Code looks OK and should work. The only problem might be if there are several layers with the same id.

Comment: It's working only on imageOverlay
For some reason it's not working on the Features

Comment: Have you checked layer.id of features? Is it different for different layers?

Comment: Yes they are unique. Auto generated by leaflet on creation (_leaflet_id)

Comment: This seems not to be so. When you add layer to `this.visibleLayers` by `this.visibleLayers.set(layer.id, fg)` statement, you are using `layer.id` property, which comes from input feature `layer` parameter, not from newly created Leaflet layer `fg`.

Comment: layer is a JSON object that I store in `this.visibleLayers` to use it later.
Each layer object is affected to one `featuregroup`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic. You say that you store your JSON objects in `this.visibleLayers`, but you are also storing Leaflet layers in it with `this.visibleLayers.set(layer.id, fg)` statement. I don't understand this.

Comment: It's a (key, value) array where the key is corresponding to the JSON object identifier. It's just to manage created featuregroups later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store each Leaflet layer in `this.visibleLayers` by it's Leaflet internal unique id, you have to retrieve it from layer with `L.Util.stamp` method.

Also `fg.hasLayer` method is not used correctly. If you want to check existence of layers in `fg` group layers, you have to check `fg.getLayers().length` value.

Your code for adding layer to `this.visibleLayers` for later usage should the look something like this:

```
if (fg.getLayers().length > 0) {
  this.carte.addLayer(fg);
  this.visibleLayers.set(L.Util.stamp(fg), fg);
}
```

Then to bring it to the front:

```
bringToFront(layer): void {
    const fg = this.visibleLayers.get(L.Util.stamp(layer));
    if (fg !== undefined) {
      fg.bringToFront();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear.

What I need is beeing able to sort FeatureGroups.
One FeatureGroup contain either an `imageOverLay` or a collection of features of `MultiPolygon`.

Each FeatureGroup is store in `this.visibleLayers` and has for `key` the `id` of my JSON object so I can retrive it later.

Comment: To interact with the map I have on the side a list that displays for each row details informations of each feature group
On click from the list I call `bringToFront()` and I pass the corresponding JSON object from the list.
Then I retrive the corresponding `FeatureGroup` from `this.visibleLayers` using the JSON object id

For some reason that I failed to identify it's not working on my collection of features of multipolygon.

I hope it's more clear.

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Sorry, but amongst all your explanations I'm lost. If you publish all relevant code in your question, I'll at least understand what is happening.

Comment: Ok but for you a map of FeatureGroups containing imageOverlays or multiple layers of Features can be ordered or not ?

Comment: You can order layers and group layers, but you cannot order features within a group layer.